# Firebase Performance Monitoring Network Report not appear on some device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

We have integrated all the dependencies and plugin what ever is mentioned in “Get Started with Firebase Performance Monitoring for Android ”.

I was able to build and run successfully on Xiaomi Mi 8 and Emulator running Android P OS, and I can see all reports on The Dashboard, but on some old device running OS below Oreo the network report is not appear.

I currently use retorfit 2.3 and okhttp 3.10. Can somebody tell me what I need to do in order to see my network requests in Firebase Performance?

Thanks in advance.